# Is there an offline MinGW installer?

Tags: c, gcc, windows-installer, installation

I am learning C and I want to install MinGW on my laptop. The MinGW installer is a *web-installer*, it requires the computer to have access to the internet when installing. But the problem is that my computer's not connected to the internet. So it can't be installed.

So I am thinking of downloading the complete offline installer on my smart-phone and transfering it to my PC through blue-tooth.

I have already tried TDM-GCC, but even that requires me to download somthing.

So is there an offline installer to MinGW? If yes where can I get it?

Comment: Take a look: https://code.google.com/p/mingw-offline-install/downloads/detail?name=mingw-6.3.exe&can=2&q=

Comment: STL maintains a nice packaged version of MingW on [his website](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).

Comment: @Kerrek SB But is it trustable?

Comment: @duDE is it trustable?

Comment: @Kerrek SB is that a trustable and reliable site. I wont get mallwares, right? And is the version stable and secure?

Comment: @Switch: What really is trust? The site owner is Microsoft's library maintainer.

Comment: You can tether your smartphone connection to your laptop. Just try to indicate that this is a metered connection and preferably do this at the end of your billing cycle. This should do the trick for you, but I would appreciate if an up to date offline installer was available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did not find an offline installer for MinGW,but instead I found a better Windows port; which is [MinGW-W64](http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php)

From http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php:

> Mingw-w64 is an advancement of the original mingw.org project, created to support the GCC compiler on Windows systems. It has forked it in 2007 in order to provide support for 64 bits and new APIs. It has since then gained widespread use and distribution.

Now to answer this question: it has to be mannually installed by downloading the zip file. It won't require additional download.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393755/mingw-w64-offline-installer) about offline install of MinGW-W64.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from link : https://github.com/jonasstrandstedt/MinGW
You need to extract the MinGW folder in C:\  eg: c:\MinGW . Then what you need to follow the steps given in the link above. In CodeBlock IDE go to settings>compiler>Tochain Executables. There you need to click on auto detect or specify the folder manually.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct answer to the question "*Is there an offline MinGW installer?*" is "*maybe, but it would be a snapshot from the past, and it's almost certainly not up-to-date with the latest available released versions.*"  The individual packages are made available (almost) as soon as they're released, so capturing everything in a self-contained installer is a moving target.

**But**, you can use the standard installer offline with a bit of prep work if you use MSYS2's `pacman`, which manages dependencies and grabs all the right versions for you.

The details are given in [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46791235/) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46791235/).