# MinGW exe cleaning

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

What is the purpose of these strange strings that are automatically included inside my exe bytes?

I found these things at the strings section of my exe while opening it with an hexadecimal editor :

> libgcj-16.dll._Jv_RegisterClasses... @.Mingw runtime failure:..
> VirtualQuery failed for %d bytes at address %p.... Unknown pseudo
> relocation protocol version %d..... Unknown pseudo relocation bit size
> %d.....

It seem `libgcj-16.dll` is related to Java, so I don't understand why this have to be there as my soft do not use Java.
The results I have found seems related to when compiling MinGW...
Using "Dependency Walker 2.2" is likely saying me that there is no need for libgcj-16.dll inside my exe.
And not any `*libgcj*` file is present inside my hard drive.

It's also not clear why these MinGW related text are present, when these strings will be used/displayed?

I have tried to erase all these things with 0x00 and it seem that my tiny soft is always working.

So is there a compiler option to avoid removing these by hand?
That can become tricky when the strings present in the soft grow.
I'm ok to eventually keep the "GCC: (tdm-1) 5.1.0", but I don't want at all anything related to Java or unused DLL, and I prefer to remove useless text.

My **main.c** is just :

```
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

My **building commands** and result :

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -Os -c "C:\Dev\Win32\Empty\main.c" -o obj\Release\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Release\Empty.exe obj\Release\main.o -s  
Output file is bin\Release\Empty.exe with size 8.50 KB
```

I compile with Code::Block (MinGW 5.1.0).
About not any building option/property is present inside my project (Console or GUI change nothing, selected platform to only Windows too).
Very thanks for your hints...

### --- UPDATE ---

So I do not have any functional problem with my soft, it is mainly about aesthetic "problem" with the exe hex content, as said by M.M in comments.
But it is also to understand why an empty soft like this one, have already some defined strings, whereas my main.c is empty and do nothing.

I'm asking me the purpose of these predefined strings, so at what they serve?
If the answer is they serve nothing inside your soft and will never be displayed and you can even not get a pointer to them, so why the compiler include them in my exe and so create useless "hex noise"...

I suspect these strings can serve and be displayed, during the compilation. (or maybe for debugging purpose)

I also suspect that these strings are coming from some linked library, like the libmingw32.a (that I have just now discovered when my `Empty.exe` have popup me `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing`, after compiling it with mingw-w64, wow I need some extra dll with gcc now! It's new to me but I suspect that my previous codeblocks version was automatically statically linking these, so I have never spot that)

And it seems that "many" libraries will be automatically "linked", even if I do not supply any linking in my building command.

Here are the process steps that are done under the hood with mingw-w64 8.1.0 :

`gcc.exe -Os -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -c main.c -o main.o`

```
Call C:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/cc1.exe -quiet -iprefix C:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/ -U_REENTRANT main.c -quiet -dumpbase main.c -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase-strip main.o -Os -o C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccMK0Jka.s

Call C:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -o main.o C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccMK0Jka.s
```

`g++.exe -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o Empty.exe main.o -s`

```
Call C:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=C:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccIhpVxg.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-liconv -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt --sysroot=C:/mingw810/i686-810-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32 -m i386pe -Bdynamic -o Empty.exe -s C:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o C:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0 -LC:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../lib -LC:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../.. main.o -Bstatic -lstdc++ -Bdynamic -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -liconv -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt C:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/crtend.o

Another truncated call similar to the very long previous C:/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe -plugin C:/...
```

Using the mingw-w64 5.4.0 and the `libgcj-16.dll` will come back, as in my old mingw 5.1.0, so it seems it is a normal thing and is not related to a safety problem. (finally libgcj-16.dll is just there as a strings, and not included as a true dll, "as I understand")

Finally I get much more "strange strings" inside my exe using the mingw-w64 8.1.0... (and the size of Empty.exe have grow from 8.50KB to 13.50KB, it's not the actual subject but I'm also looking at creating the most tiny possible size, but I prefer speed instead size)

Here are the new strange things present inside Empty.exe compiled by mingw-w64 8.1.0 :

> libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.__register_frame_info.__deregister_frame_info....
> c@.@`@. .@...@...@..c@. €@.........Unknown error..._matherr(): %s in
> %s(%g, %g)  (retval=%g)...Argument domain error (DOMAIN).Argument
> singularity (SIGN)..Overflow range error (OVERFLOW).The result is too
> small to be represented (UNDERFLOW)...Total loss of significance
> (TLOSS)..Partial loss of significance
> (PLOSS)....¤@@.Ã@@.à@@..A@.8A@.\A@.Mingw-w64 runtime failure:..Address
> %p has no image-section. VirtualQuery failed for %d bytes at address
> %p.... VirtualProtect failed with code 0x%x.. Unknown pseudo
> relocation protocol version %d..... Unknown pseudo relocation bit size
> %d.....GCC: (i686-win32-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
> 8.1.0

I see that my question does not interest a lot, though it seems to me an important ask to better understand what our soft contain.

So I will accept any answer that give some insightful on these "strange things"...

My **main ask** is : When these strange/unknown strings auto included in my exe will be used?

Comment: Are you sure that the executable that produces the message is in fact your program?  You can verify that (or refute it) by running the program manually from a command-line window.  I have no expectation that any version of g++ would include libgcj in the link without being explicitly asked to do so, and the link command presented does not ask for that, so my first guess is that the message you ask about is not coming from your program (more likely it's from your IDE itself).

Comment: Have compiled it by hand and the compiled exe always contain these strange things, damn... What others things are included in my exe that I'm not able to see... What do you suggest to me? Do you have an link for a safe version of MinGW? Or i have to try compiling it myself under Windows...? My actual version is coming from `codeblocks-17.12mingw-nosetup.zip`

Comment: I would recommend using mingw-w64.  The old mingw.org project has lots of bugs and very slow development which is why it was forked

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think he is saying that running the executable does not produce any errors, but he finds some aesthetic problem with the bytes that make up the executable file on disk

Comment: I add that I saw these strange things inside the exe file, opening `Empty.exe` with an hexadecimal editor, and the place of these things seems inside the strings "section" of the exe. I want to be able to compile from an 32bit system, does it is possible with mingw-w64?

Comment: yes, mingw-w64 can have win32 and win64 for each of the build system and target system separately

Comment: I do not found which file to download inside the mingw-w64 sourceforge page, have tried `mingw-w64-v7.0.0.zip` that do not contain any mingw exe files. And I'm looking for an offline installer. Please if you can show me the right link to choose... (there are so many files there)

Comment: Ok, it seems I have found what i need... I will test later and say you the result... Thanks you! [offline installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393755/mingw-w64-offline-installer) and [sjlj or dwarf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670169/what-is-difference-between-sjlj-vs-dwarf-vs-seh)

Comment: I have update my question, I hope that someone have at least an answer to my end ask... Anyway, thanks again for the mingw-w64 advice, now I have the opportunity to test newer versions of gcc...

Comment: You might be able to answer your own question by downloading the gcc and/or mingw-w64 source code and finding those strings (by grep or whatever) and seeing how they are used