# Is there a way to install GCC on a Windows 10 machine that can't go online?

Tags: c, windows, gcc

All the installers that I've found seem to require a live internet connection to download the files. Is there an offline installer available to install GCC on my Windows 10 machine (that cannot be connected to the internet)? I've seen a possible solution where you install it on a machine with an internet connection then create an offline installer from that - but unsure how to do this.

Have tried AaronDanielson's answer in [Is there an offline MinGW installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028808/is-there-an-offline-mingw-installer) but get "failed retrieving file 'offline.db' from disk: couldn't open file..." to install MingGW-w64.

Comment: Are you allowed to install some [Debian](https://debian.org/) distribution from CDROM (or USB)? Are you allowed to compile [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyCC) then use it to compile some *old* GCC from its source code? Did you read [Thompson's Turing award paper](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf) ? Did your boss read that old paper?

Comment: you tried the answer there but **which answer** and which compiler? TDM-GCC, mingw-w64 and mingw are completely different with mingw being the worst

Answer (score 3):

The GCC install is in a certain way portable.

Install on a machine that is online, and copy the resulting C:\Mingw* folders to the machine that isn't online. It works.